# Issue with passing integer vertex attributes with "in" keyword

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

I'm working on bone animation. I have a vertex struct that basically looks like

```cpp
struct MeshVertex
{
    glm::vec3 pos;
    glm::vec3 normal;
    glm::vec2 tex;
    glm::vec3 tangent;
    glm::vec3 bitangent;
    uint32_t ids[4] = {};
    float weights[4] = {};

    void print() const;
};
```

The mesh is a basic cube with one bone. Therefore `ids = {0,0,0,0}` and `weights = {1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f}` for every single vertex. In my mesh class I have a static function `Mesh::genFormat()` that handles attributes. `vao` is a static `int` in the mesh class and `for_i` is just a convenient macro I use to do for loops. Note that I correctly use glVertexArrayAttrib**I**Format.

```cpp
Mesh::Mesh(const std::vector<MeshVertex>& vertices, const std::vector<uint>& indices, const std::vector<Texture>& textures)
{
    m_textures = textures;
    m_num_indices = indices.size();
        
    // create vertex and index buffers
    glCreateBuffers(1, &m_vbo);
    glCreateBuffers(1, &m_ibo);
    glNamedBufferData(m_vbo, sizeof(MeshVertex) * vertices.size(), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glNamedBufferData(m_ibo, sizeof(uint) * indices.size(), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void Mesh::genFormat()
{
    glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    for_i(7) { glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, i); }
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, offsetof(MeshVertex, pos)));
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, offsetof(MeshVertex, normal));
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 2, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, offsetof(MeshVertex, tex));
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 3, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, offsetof(MeshVertex, tangent));
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 4, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, offsetof(MeshVertex, bitangent));
        
    glVertexArrayAttribIFormat(vao, 5, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, offsetof(MeshVertex, ids)));
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 6, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, offsetof(MeshVertex, weights)));

    for_i(7) { glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, i, 0); }

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

The following GLSL won't render anything.

```c
#version 460 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 Pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 Normal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 Tex;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 Tan;
layout(location = 4) in vec3 BiTan;
layout(location = 5) in uvec4 BoneIds;
layout(location = 6) in vec4 Weights;

out vec3 normal;
out vec2 tex;

layout(binding = 2, std140) uniform Camera
{
    mat4 VP;
    vec4 cpos;
};

uniform mat4 node;
uniform mat4 bones_inverse_bind_mesh_parent[50];

void main()
{
    tex = Tex;

    mat4 W = mat4(0.0f);
    if (Weights[0] != 0.0f)
    {
        for (uint i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            W = W + (Weights[i] * bones_inverse_bind_mesh_parent[BoneIds[i]]);
            
        W = node * W;
    }
    else
        W = node;
    
    gl_Position = VP * W * vec4(Pos, 1.0);
}
```

Since `BoneIds[i]` is always zero, if I replace

```c
W = W + (Weights[i] * bones_inverse_bind_mesh_parent[BoneIds[i]]);
```

with

```c
W = W + (Weights[i] * bones_inverse_bind_mesh_parent[0]);
```

the result should be unchanged. My matrix transforms are currently a bit off (something to fix later), but now the cube renders fine. So there is something wrong with `BoneIds`. After bashing my head against the wall on this for a while, I instead replaced

```c
layout(location = 5) in uvec4 BoneIds;
```

with

```c
layout(location = 5) varying uvec4 BoneIds;
```

after seeing some old GLSL online, and now everything works. What I don't understand is why. I've seen plenty of GLSL code on the internet work with integer attributes using the `in` keyword.

UPDATE :

If I replace glVertexArrayAttrib**I**Format in `Mesh::genFormat()` with

```cpp
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 5, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, false, offsetof(MeshVertex, ids));
```

in C++ and

```c
layout(location = 5) in vec4 BoneIds;
```

in GLSL and cast bone ids from float to int in the glsl code, the code also works.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the VBO part - glVertexArrayVertexBuffer . I do not see anything wrong the posted code. Drivers do a lot of magic behind the scenes so plenty of incorrect code can work until changed slightly. So, I would still look for some error. Try changing the location values, it might break the new code too if there are still some hidden errors in it.

Comment: @Quimby You mentioning drivers gave me the idea to check the nvidia control panel, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved the issue, even though I don't quite understand how this fixes the problem. My preferred graphics processor was on auto but when I forced it to use the NVIDIA processor over my integrated graphics, everything works out fine. [image of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXc4d.png)

Update :

I think it is as simple as my Intel processor graphics supporting OpenGL 4.4 and `glVertexArrayAttribIFormat` came about in OpenGL 4.5.

Comment: Be very careful with doing this. It is exactly what I was talking about, there might still be an error in your code but NVIDIA drivers will fix this while Intel's won't. E.g. if you remove the explicit locations there is still a good chance that the driver will assign the same numbers but it might not, it might even change between shader compilations. From my experience NVIDIA fixes a lot of stuff, Intel the least (which is not a bad thing), AMD is so so. Take advantage of your two GPUs and ensure it works on both (unless it is a toy project for you eyes only of course).

Comment: Thanks, this is good advice. I will be more cognizant of the GPU in the future!